# C++ Error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a compiler from scratch, on the main.cpp I'm trying to read the file, but as soon as I compile it gives me an error:

> Error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpremissive]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Parser 0.1\n" << endl;

    FILE * fh = fopen("C:\\file.bpc", "r"); // file location is correct
    if(!fh){ cerr << "Cannot find file" << endl; }
    fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t fileSize = ftell(fh);
    fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
    string fileContents(fileSize, ' ');
    fread(fileContents.data(), 1, fileSize, fh); // HERE THE ERROR OCCURRES

    cout << fileContents << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `.data()` is a `const` member function in your unspecified version of C++, I guess. It seems only C++17 added non-const `.data()`.

Comment: You should use C++17 or later. [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::data - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: ...but you should rather use C++ stdlib functions to read into the C++ string, not old C ones. Then this would be a non-issue, as e.g. you could write to the `.begin()` iterator, which has a non-`const` overload. Basically, you shouldn't have to use `void*` in C++, and if you find yourself using it, you probably have a bad design. Strong typing exists!

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for the advice, as you can see, I've changed the code using Fstream.

Comment: If you found a solution and if your satisfied with it, please add it as an answer rather than adding it to the question itself. It'll greatly help some one else who would stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

That's the code that I used to solve the problem, instead of reading the file in a C style, I used fstream library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Parser 0.1\n" << endl;

    string line;
    ifstream file; // Instead of ofstream that creates I file as far as I understand
    file.open("C:\\main1.bpc");
    if(file.is_open()){
        while(getline(file,line)){
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    else cerr << "Unable to open the file" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```